# Bash script syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, ubuntu

im trying to create a simple bash script to create and delete a user on ubunutu , here is my script

> sudo nano createuser.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

choice=2
# Main Display
echo "Enter Number to select an option"
echo
echo "1) Add User"
echo "2) Delete User"
echo
while [ $choice -eq 2 ]; do
    read choice
    if [ $choice -eq 1] ;
    then
        echo -e "Enter Username"
        read user_name
        echo -e "Enter Password"
        read user_passwd
        sudo useradd $user_name -m -p $user_passwd
        cat /etc/passwd
    else if [$choise -eq 2] ; then
        cat /etc/passwd
        echo -e "Enter Password"
        read del_passwd
        echo -e "User to be deleted:"
        read del_user
        sudo userdel -r $del_user
        cat /etc/passwd
        echo
    fi
```

im not sure if there s a typo on my script ,or something else .
whenever i execute the script i get this message

> Enter Number to select an option
>
> 1. Add User
> 2. Delete User

> ./createuser.sh: line 31: syntax error: unexpected end of file

thank you in advance for your help !!

Comment: You have `choice` and `choise`. Typo?

Comment: A `while`-loop is concluded by a `done` statement.

Comment: Your `else`-clause is a subclause to the previous `if`, which as far as I can tell then misses its own `fi`-statement.

Comment: `[` and `]` keywords need spaces all around them.

Comment: I think you want `elif` instead of `else if` -- the `else if` version starts a second `if` block inside the first, so you'd need two `fi`s to close both of them. I always recommend [Shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) for spotting common problems, but in this case it just can't figure out what's going on (other than the missing spaces around `[` and `]`).

Answer (score 2):

Errors:

1. wrong `if/else/fi` sequence, what you have is basically this w few errors

```
if [ ]
then
   # something
else
   if [ ]
   then
      # something else
   fi
# fi should be here ti close outer if []
```

2. In bash you have `if then/elif/else` closed by `fi` So something like this

```
if []
then
   # something
elif []
then
   # something else happened
else
   # something else than elif happened
fi
```

3. `;` after `if []`, it only goes there if `if` and `than` are in the same line, like so

```
if [] ; then
   # something
elif []
   # something else happened
else
   # something else than elif happened
fi
```

4. space inside test brackets `[]`

```
if [ a -eq 5 ]
#   ^       ^
#   +-------+----< notice space here
```

5. In bash `while` sequence goes as following `while [ ] do done`. like following

```
while [ i -le 55 ]
do
  # do something
done
```

Suggestions

1. use `-s` for reading in password in bash to hide it while typing.

Conclusion, with all the fixes above here is working script:

```
#!/bin/bash

choice=2
# Main Display
echo "Enter Number to select an option"
echo
echo "1) Add User"
echo "2) Delete User"
echo
while [ $choice -eq 2 ] 
do
    read choice
    if [ $choice -eq 1 ] 
    then
        echo -e "Enter Username"
        read user_name
        echo -e "Enter Password"
        read user_passwd
        sudo useradd $user_name -m -p $user_passwd
        cat /etc/passwd
    elif [ $choise -eq 2 ] 
    then 
        cat /etc/passwd
        echo -e "Enter Password"
        read del_passwd
        echo -e "User to be deleted:"
        read del_user
        sudo userdel -r $del_user
        cat /etc/passwd
        echo
    else
        echo "Wrong option you have 1 or 2"                                                                                                                   
    fi  
done
```

Comment: thank you , the script is not working on user delete

Comment: @KarimHassani what do you mean it does not work?

Comment: i was getting an error message at the end when i execute the script via ssh - unary operator expected
i just fixed the script the result is below ,thank you again KPCT

Answer (score 0):

yes guys ,thank you so much for your help
i just fixed it

here is my working script now

```
#!/bin/bash

choice=2
# Main display echo "Enter number to select an option" echo echo "1) Add User" echo "2) Delete User" echo

while [[ "$choice" -eq 2 ]];  do

read choice 

if [[ "$choice" -eq 1 ]] ; then    

    echo -e "Enter Username"
    read user_name 
    echo -e "Enter Password"
    read user_passwd 
    sudo useradd "$user_name" -m -p "$user_passwd"
    cat  /etc/passwd   else

            if [[ "$choice" -eq 2 ]] ; then
            cat  /etc/passwd 
            echo
            echo -e "User to be deleted:"
            read del_user 
            sudo userdel -r "$del_user"
            cat  /etc/passwd
            echo

                        choice=2
                fi   
        fi 

done
```

Comment: you have unnecessary `if` statement in your code here.